# fill variable width column(s) with fixed width/height 'items' dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I have a 3 col layout (fixed center, var Left & Right side cols) and want to fill the 2 side cols with adsense ads as many as I can fit.  I'm thinking dynamically generate the js to fill the columns (since I don't know how wide they could be and float the ads to fill it).  But how do I detect with js that the column is filled (ads are fixed 200x200px) both height and width wise?  I'm thinking there must be a solution already out there, preferably w/ jquery, but haven't been able to google anything so far.

Also, can I stagger the ad display because it slows the intial page load?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: I can't wait to never frequent your ad-ridden site

Comment: You can get the height of an element (like your ad container) via jQuery or various other frameworks.  Of course when your user resizes the browser window, the height changes.

Comment: @Hunter - you made me laugh... my client's site - I don't particularly like ads myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for an FYI for anyone new to adsense - only 3 adsense ads per page.  But thanks @Pointy - I was able to generate my own little fill the columns.